# Django - Get urls of all images that reference a Post?

Tags: python, django

I have this model where a Post can have many Photos. I'm trying to retrieve all posts, including `ImageField` url attribute (according to Django docs FileField and ImageField have a url attribute). So I'd like to ideally return all the urls of the images associated with the post (ideally in order of created).

model.py

```
class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_id")
    goal_id = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)


class Photo(AbstractBaseModel):
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path)
```

view.py

```
def get(self, request):
    data = Post.objects.order_by('created').values('body', 'goal_id__description', 'created',
                                                   'creator_id__username', replies=Count('replypost'),
                                                   cheers=Count('cheerpost'), image_urls='photo__image_url')
    return Response(list(data), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Please don't use `.values(...)` to perform a JSON encoding. One can use serializers for that. BY using `.values(..)` a JOIN will act as a "multiplier" to other `JOIN`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you perhaps write up a solution as an example for me please? I'm not sure how you would use a serializer for this. What do you mean by a "multiplier" to other JOINs?

Comment: I guess you would use this data as API data, if yes you have better to use `Rest Framework` else send the data to your views and parse it in templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do *not* use [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) to perform JSON serialization. This will errode the logical layer of a model, and for related objects it will act as a multiplier: per related `Photo` the `body`, etc. will be repeated.

We can define a function to retrieve the image URL of a `Photo` with:

```
class Photo(AbstractBaseModel):
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path)

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        return self.image.url
```

You can work with a serializers that determine how to return objects. For the `Photo`, we can work with a `PhotoSerializer`:

```
class PostSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_urls = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        source='photo_set', many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='image_url'
    )
    creator_name = serializers.SlugField()
    replies = serializers.IntegerField()
    cheers = serializers.IntegerField()
    goal_description = serializers.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body', 'goal_id', 'created', 'creator_name', 'goal_description', 'replies', 'cheers', 'created')
```

Then we can serialize and return the coressponding serialized data with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Count, Prefetch

def get(self, request):
    items = Post.objects.order_by('created').annotate(
        creator_name = F('creator_id__username'),
        goal_description = F('goal_id__description'),
        replies=Count('replypost', distinct=True),
        cheers=Count('cheerpost', distinct=True),
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('photo_set', Photo.objects.order_by('created'))
    )
    serializer = PostSerialiser(items, many=True)
    return Response({'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by it'll "erode the logical layer of the model?"

Comment: @user8714896: you will retrieve dictionaries, not `Post` objects, this means that no `ForeignKey`s can be fetched, that the [`get_FOO_display` methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) are not available for fields with choices, etc. So all the extra tooling a model offers is not available, since these are *simple* dictionaries.

Comment: does this pass to say a React Native front-end well? I happened to notice that some of the key value pairs are string to a Django class like UUID or DateTime.

Comment: @user8714896: no, a `DateTimeField` will return a `datetime` object. By making use of serializers, it will by default use an ISO 8601 datetime string, which is usually how datetimes are passed in JSON blobs.

Comment: do you have anything I could read regarding using serializers to return data in the way you have here. I want to better understand what's going on here rather than copy pasting.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Django REST framework tutorial: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: @user8714896: one of the main points is, if you would like to serializer a `Post` and you use `'photo__image', it would make multiple copies of the same `Post` object, each time with a different `photo__image`, and to make matters even worse, it will return the path stored in the database, not the media URL.